# Sculpting with both Z and X axis symmetry?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, sculpt, blend-modes

Pretty simple question, i would really like to sculpt some pillars that are symmetrical on both the x and z axis, is there any way at all to enable this in blender? or is there a way to make a model symmetrical along both the x and z axis once modelled?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: 2.7:[image]

or 2.8:

[image]

Also, once modeled, you can delete some parts and add a mirror modifier, which can work on X and Z (Pivot point of mirroring is the origin of the object).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mirror modifier after you sculpt.  Select X, Z, and Clipping.